# How do I make a <li> element semantically part of another <ul> when it is defined outside of it

Tags: html

Here is a simplified version of my code. It is not possible to place the fourth list item inside the "my_list" element in my project for some difficult to explain reason. Therefore, I need some other way to make HTML understand that it is supposed to be part of the same list.

Obviously the belongsTo attribute does not exist, but something like that would be nice in this case.

```
<ul id="my_list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
...
... (other content)
...
<li belongsTo="my_list">item 4</li>
```

EDIT:

to specify, I am looking for the same effect you would get from:

```
<form id="my_form">
  <!-- (form content) -->
<form>

<input form="my_form">
```

Comment: you could technically do it exactly like you suggested inventing an attribute like that but if you want the dom to know that list item to be part of the above collection you are expected to run a javascript on document load that will append such element to the real list

Comment: Surely if the content in between is not part of the list then it wouldn't be semantically correct for that bullet to be part of that list - you should start a new list - or perhaps a list is completely wrong and you should be using sections and headings instead

Answer (score 1):

you could technically do it exactly like you suggested inventing an attribute like that but if you want the dom to know that list item to be part of the above collection you are expected to run a javascript on document load that will append such element to the real list.

This is an example of page that will run a js on document ready and will move every element found with the attribute `data-belongsto` inside the expected parent:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

  const belongsToElements = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-belongsto]');  
  for(let el of belongsToElements){
    const belongsTo = el.dataset.belongsto;    
    const parent = document.getElementById(belongsTo);
    parent.appendChild(el);
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="my_list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

...
... (other content)
...

<li data-belongsTo="my_list">item 4</li>
```